# How to convert array of directory tree structure/files and size in ul li list

Tags: php, arrays

i have a directory tree in array like this .

where the **key is full file path** and **value is the filesize**.

```
Array
(
    [directory1\file1.jpg] => 197602
    [directory1\file2.jpg] => 274893
    [directory2\file1.txt] => 41
    [directory2\file2.txt] => 41
    [directory2\sub-directory1\file1.txt] => 47
    [directory2\sub-directory1\file2.txt] => 41
    [directory2\sub-directory1\file3.txt] => 47
    [file1.txt] => 41
    [file2.txt] => 47
)
```

and i am trying to create directory tree using ul li like this.

```
<ul class="filetree">
    <li class="closed"><span class="folder">directory1</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="hvr"><span class="file">file1.jpg</span><span></span><span class="right">197602</span></li>
            <li class="hvr"><span class="file">file2.jpg</span><span></span><span class="right">274893</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="closed"><span class="folder">directory2</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="closed"><span class="folder">sub-directory1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="hvr"><span class="file">file1.txt</span><span></span><span class="right">47</span></li>
                    <li class="hvr"><span class="file">file2.txt</span><span></span><span class="right">41</span></li>
                    <li class="hvr"><span class="file">file3.txt</span><span></span><span class="right">47</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="hvr"><span class="file">file1.txt</span><span></span><span class="right">41</span></li>
            <li class="hvr"><span class="file">file2.txt</span><span></span><span class="right">41</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="hvr"><span class="file">file1.txt</span><span></span><span class="right">41</span></li>
    <li class="hvr"><span class="file">file2.txt</span><span></span><span class="right">47</span></li>
</ul>
```

above, every directory and file uses `<li>` but just a different class , but file/directory inside other directory uses `<ul> <li>`
using foreach loop.

so far i have come up with this.

```
<?php

$array =    Array
    (
        'directory1\file1.jpg' => 197602,
        'directory1\file2.jpg' => 274893,
        'directory2\file1.txt' => 41,
        'directory2\file2.txt' => 41,
        'directory2\sub-directory1\file1.txt' => 47,
        'directory2\sub-directory1\file2.txt' => 41,
        'directory2\sub-directory1\file3.txt' => 47,
        'file1.txt' => 41,
        'file2.txt' => 47
    );

    print_r($array);



    foreach($array as $path => $size){

        if(strpos($path,'\\') !== false) {
        //file is under a directory tree/structure 

        $directory_tree = explode('\\',$path);

//create directories using li class

//last element in array is filename. 

        print_r($directory_tree );

        }else{
        //its just file, no directories to create

        echo '<li class="hvr"><span class="file">'.$path.'</span><span></span><span class="right">'.$size.'</span></li>';

        }

    }
```

https://eval.in/172034

how do i keep track of already created directories or i have to normalize the above array ,

like

```
Array
(
    [directory1] Array(
                        [file1.jpg] => 197602
                        [file2.jpg] => 274893
                        )

    [directory2]Array(
                        [file1.txt] => 41
                        [file2.txt] => 41
                        [sub-directory1]Array(
                                                [file1.txt] => 41
                                                [file2.txt] => 44
                                                [file3.txt] => 54
                                                )

                    )
    [file1.txt] => 41
    [file2.txt] => 47
)
```

so it will be easier to create html according to the elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :

```
$array =  array(
        'directory1\file1.jpg' => 197602,
        'directory1\file2.jpg' => 274893,
        'directory2\file1.txt' => 41,
        'directory2\file2.txt' => 41,
        'directory2\sub-directory1\file1.txt' => 47,
        'directory2\sub-directory1\file2.txt' => 41,
        'directory2\sub-directory1\file3.txt' => 47,
        'file1.txt' => 41,
        'file2.txt' => 47
    );
$result=array();


foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key,'\\') !== false) {
        $key = explode("\\", $key);
        if(isset($key[1]) && !isset($key[2])){
            $result[$key[0]][$key[1]] = $value;
        }
        if(isset($key[2])){
            $result[$key[0]][$key[1]][$key[2]] = $value;
        }
    }else{
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [directory1] => Array
        (
            [file1.jpg] => 197602
            [file2.jpg] => 274893
        )

    [directory2] => Array
        (
            [file1.txt] => 41
            [file2.txt] => 41
            [sub-directory1] => Array
                (
                    [file1.txt] => 47
                    [file2.txt] => 41
                    [file3.txt] => 47
                )

        )

    [file1.txt] => 41
    [file2.txt] => 47
)
```

Comment: thanks for your input, it looks like the simplified directory structure , but it will only work for 2 directories deep, how can i create something for n directories deep.

Comment: you just need to test of how many elements there's in `$key = explode("\\", $key);` and play along :)